# Can I Make Applescript to Count Number of Files Created?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, automator, automation

I would like to start learning AppleScript.

I want to add to my workflow a counter that will keep track of the amount of PDFs i create for a job and keep a tally of those documents.  I can then forget about this file until it's time for review and I have a concrete display of my productivity.  Ideally I would like a "droplet" I can have in the dock so I can drag my work files on the app and generate an inventory over time.

I aped this and it looks promising but it stays at "1" every time i use it:

```
increment()

on increment()
    set currentCount to currentCount + 1
    display dialog "Count is now " & currentCount & "."
end increment
```

How do I keep it going?

Comment: I would suggest investigating Folder Actions. That way, any file added to the folder will trigger the script.

Comment: Thanks for replying!  I thought about that but I store every file in different folders, so I'm thinking this would have to be before I move them into storage

Comment: Nice work putting up a sample script. I’m tempted to append the file name and date  one per line to a log file - then you could use a second script to output the counts as needed. Also, our friends awk grep and wc can count lines and filter text file contents or csv file contents with ease.

Comment: Another option would be to have the droplet append to a log and prompt for a location to move the items.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Looks like I'm just going to manually enter the data into an excel file. I'm not going to figure out any kind of automation.  Appreciate the help tho

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a Service/Quick Action for Finder and use a shortcut instead. It will check the currently selected files and add them to your computer in a comma-separated values (CSV) file. Whenever you press the shortcut, it will count the selected files, update the .csv, and append the filenames to the log. Finally, you want a notification to help you check if the process is working. Some error handling is also advised.

**To create a Service that runs this script:**

1. Open Automator and create a new Service or Quick Action.
2. Set the service to receive 'no input' in 'Finder.'
3. Add a 'Run AppleScript' action and paste the script into it.
4. Save the service and assign a shortcut to it through System Preferences >
   Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services.

Update the first line with the *username* and path you wish to use:

```
property csvPath : "Macintosh HD:Users:Username:Desktop:file_log.csv" -- Update with the actual path to your CSV file

on run
    -- Try to get the selected files from Finder
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        try
            set selectedFiles to selection as alias list
            if (count selectedFiles) ≤ 0 then
                display notification "No files selected." with title "Error"
                return
            end if
        on error
            display notification "Error accessing selected files in Finder."
            return
        end try
    end tell
    
    -- Initialize the list of logged files and total count
    set loggedFiles to {}
    set totalCount to 0
    
    -- Attempt to read existing CSV data and count
    try
        set fileRef to open for access file csvPath
        set eofPosition to get eof fileRef
        if eofPosition > 0 then
            set fileContents to read fileRef
            set loggedFiles to paragraphs of fileContents
            set totalCount to count of loggedFiles
        end if
        close access fileRef
    on error errMsg number errNum
        -- Handle specific file errors
        close access fileRef -- Ensure file is closed after error
        if errNum is -43 then -- File not found
            -- No file found, proceed as if it's a new log
        else
            display dialog "Error reading from CSV file: " & errMsg
            return
        end if
    end try
    
    -- Check each selected file against logged files
    set newFiles to {}
    repeat with aFile in selectedFiles
        try
            -- Convert the Finder selection to a file alias and get its name
            set filePath to POSIX path of (aFile as text)
            tell application "System Events"
                set fileName to name of disk item filePath
            end tell
            
            -- Check if the file is already logged
            set end of newFiles to fileName
            set totalCount to totalCount + 1 -- Increment total count for each new file
        on error errMsg number errNum
            display dialog "Error processing a file: " & errMsg & " (Error Number: " & errNum & ")"
        end try
    end repeat
    
    -- Update the CSV file with the new files
    if (count newFiles) > 0 then
        try
            set fileRef to open for access file csvPath with write permission
            -- Move to end of file to append instead of overwriting
            set eof of fileRef to (get eof fileRef)
            repeat with aFile in newFiles
                write aFile & return to fileRef starting at eof
            end repeat
            close access fileRef
        on error errMsg
            display dialog "Error updating file: " & errMsg
        end try
    end if
    
    -- Notify the user of completion with the updated total count
    display notification "Added " & (count of newFiles) & " new files. Total files: " & totalCount with title "Update Complete"
end run
```

Before running the Service, you must enable [Privacy and Security access](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchl07817563/mac). Include Finder, Automator and whatever other applications you are using. Also, make sure you have writing permissions for the CSV.